# Mover directorio oracle a otra particion

Tags: linux, centos, oracle-12c

actualmente tengo un directorio U01, el cual esta montado en la partición raíz / en un linux centos 7.
esto esta causando una serie de inconvenientes, ya que el espacio en esta partición esta usado al 93%, y constantemente se llena la partición, dejando la maquina inaccesible.
Necesito poder mover el directorio U01 (donde esta instalado oracle) a la partición /home, la cual tiene espacio mas que suficiente.
cual es el mejor método para hacer esto?, por otro lado, si muevo el directorio U01, va a seguir funcionando el motor oracle en la instalación?
Gracias por sus respuestas

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Normalmente no hay lío sobre dónde se deje la carpeta base y siempre va a funcionar. La instalación siempre hace uso de las variables de entorno ORACLE_BASE, ORACLE_HOME y demás.

**2)** Es pésima idea instalar en `/home`, pues todo estará sujeto a permisos de usuario y te la vas a pasar resolviendo errores causados por ésto. Por [convención](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard), todo software de terceros (que no venga de un repo oficial, que no siga las convenciones de los paquetes instalados oficialmente) debería ir en `/opt`.

**3)** Lo más sano sería hacer backup de tus esquemas y recrear las particiones del disco, dándole más espacio a `/` (y por ahí derecho a  `/opt`) e instalando allí. Pero esa sería mi opinión.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tus comentarios. estuve investigando un poco, y tal como dices, al parecer no habra problema si muevo de particion el directorio U01. aunque si, creo que voy a optar por pedir mas espacio de almacenamiento, y crear una ´particion nueva para montar ahi este directorio con los permisos que ya tiene actualmente. Saludos